# Charles proxy shows IP addresses instead of domain names

Tags: charles-proxy

Charles for me shows IP addresses instead of domain names. Has anyone else seen this problem. See the attached screenshot.

[image: Charles screenshot]

Comment: Also seeing this. Did you ever find a solution? In my case it happens when I first install/use Charles on a machine, then after some time it will begin displaying the domain names. This also happens on co-workers machines.

Comment: I am experiencing this issue when using Charles with the Android emulator. (at the time of writing, Charles v4.1.4 and Android emulator v26.1.3)

Comment: I'm seeing this too when using Android emulator.

Comment: did you resolve this issue? because i am having the exact same issue here. It used to be able to show the hostname with https. But with latest android sdk emulator, it shows ip address for HTTPS and hostname for HTTP URL.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Charles proxy SSL connections won't show hostnames, only ips](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33724755/charles-proxy-ssl-connections-wont-show-hostnames-only-ips)

Comment: Just need to follow this and cold boot the emulator again
https://stackoverflow.com/a/52765004

Answer (score 18):

after searching for a while I found this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46054993/4231147

> 1. Setting -> Network & Internet -> Mobile network -> Access point names -> Click on the access point and set Proxy and Port properties to your charles local address (You can find it on Charles -> Help -> Local IP Address)
> 2. Save access point changes
> 3. On some versions you need to disable the airplane mode on and off to make the access point proxy effective

The menu flow is relevant for Android 8.0. on other versions, there might be a different name for some of the menu screens

Comment: It resolved my issue. It has to be marked as the answer.

Comment: on some versions you need to disable the airplane mode on and off to make the access point proxy effective. <- Lifesaver!

Answer (score 4):

For Android Emulator, adding to "gutte's " answer - if this issue still persists: it can be resolved by turning off the `Wi-fi` on the emulator and using `Mobile Data` only.

Comment: This resolved the issue for me after it persisted. thank you!

Comment: Apparently it also works if turn off Mobile Data on the emulator and use WiFi only, thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

**Cellular**

```
Edit access point -> <ip>:<port> -> Save -> Airplane mode on/off
```

[image]

**Wi-Fi**

```
Edit -> <ip>:<port> -> Save
```

[image]

Download and save certificate

```
chls.pro/ssl
//Install a certificate -> CA certificate -> Install anyway
```

From **Android N** add a configuration to your app

```
//manifest
<applicationandroid:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config">

//res/xml/network_security_config.xml
<network-security-config> 
  <debug-overrides> 
    <trust-anchors> 
      <!-- Trust user added CAs while debuggable only -->
      <certificates src="user" /> 
    </trust-anchors> 
  </debug-overrides> 
</network-security-config>
```