# Android Studio - Android Emulator Wifi Connected with No Internet

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, android-wifi

I have wasted a whole day trying out different solutions floating around in SO and other place mentioned to enable wifi on the android emulator but to no avail.
Can anybody help me figure out how do I enable internet on my android emulator?

I have Nexus 5X API 27 and target being Android 8.1 (Google Play)
and Nexus 5 API P and target being Android 7.1.1.

I believe there should be a way to enable internet on it or else the whole point of providing virtual wifi on the emulator seems to be waste.

I am on mac OS HS 10.13.4 directly connected to my router with no proxy.

I even tried deleting all the AVDs, re-installing them. I even tried having installed the latest Pixel 2 with Oreo Android 8.1

Nothing seems to be working. Has anybody faced this issue and found a solution?

Any help would be of great help

Thanks, 
Vikram

Update: When I connect my computer through my phone as hotspot wifi, the emulator has internet through wifi, but it fails when I connect my computer to my home router.

Comment: doesn't it have already enabled?

Comment: I have the very same issue. It works through my phone hotspot but not through my router. What kind of router do you have? Everything used to work fine before when I had an AVM router but now I have a Telekom Speedport router and it won't work anymore.

Comment: @TheBaj : The kind of router might not be the problem here or may be but i don't know. Try the solution below which worked for me.

Comment: @VikramMahishi just update your android sdk's emulator. It's working for me.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42736038/android-emulator-not-able-to-access-the-internet

Comment: 2021 - Google/Android still unable to create emulator capable of connecting to the internet

Comment: First of all try rebooting (rebooting the system) the emulator manually.

Comment: DISABLE ANY VPN IN ORDER TO HAVE WIFI IN THE EMULATOR

Answer (score 49, accepted):

@TheBaj : I figured the problem with this and fixed it. The problem is when you are connected through the router, the androidwifi in your emulator uses the settings and the sets the DNS to something other than 8.8.8.8 which is the google DNS(I presume this is kinda mandatory setting for the androidwifi to gain internet access). But if i change the DNS in my network settings, the google-services plugin which fetches your dependencies especially the one's getting downloaded from `jcenter()` will not be downloaded and hence your sync will fail which eventually fails your build.

So the trick is that you have your google DNS(8.8.8.8) configured in your network settings after your default router settings - this part takes care of downloading the dependencies from `jcenter()` and the sync and build succeeds.

Now launch your emulator with `emulator @Nexus_5X_API_27 -dns-server 8.8.8.8` command from the terminal which forces the emulator to use 8.8.8.8 as its DNS and the emulator will have internet.

I am working on a react-native app, so for me android studio is needless and i have configured my bashrc to launch the different emulators as follows,

```
   function emunex5 {
    emulator @Nexus_5X_API_27 -dns-server 8.8.8.8
 }

  function emunex6 {
    emulator @Nexus_6_API_27 -dns-server 8.8.8.8
  }

  function emupix {
    emulator @Pixel_XL_API_27 -dns-server 8.8.8.8
   }
```

So from one terminal i launch the emulator of my choice and then run the build on another terminal which runs my app on the launched emulator and MY FREAKING EMULATOR HAS INTERNET ACCESS. :)

Try this out and i hope this helps.

Thanks,
Vikram

Comment: 'emulator' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: @Bhupesh see `%HOME%\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator` - this is where I found it.

Answer (score 320):

Stated below are the solutions for Windows and Mac, but similar solutions will work on any OS:

1. **On Windows**

   - Open *Network and Sharing Center* and click on current *Connection*
   - Click on *Properties*
   - Double Click on *Internet Protocol Version 4 (TCP/IPv4)*
   - Set the Preferred and Alternate DNS servers as (Screenshot below) :

     ```
     8.8.8.8
     8.8.4.4
     ```
2. **On Mac**

   - Go to ***Settings > Network > Advanced... > DNS***
   - Delete whatever entries you have there and add these two entries (Screenshot below):

     ```
     8.8.8.8
     8.8.4.4
     ```

     <sub>*Note: For Mac users, if the entries field is disabled and you're not able to edit it, click on the 'Lock' icon in the bottom area of that window and enter the password to be able to make changes*</sub>

Restart the emulator, and it should solve:

Screenshots:

1. **Windows**

[image: Android emulator not connecting to internet solution on windows]

2. **Mac**

[image: Android emulator not connecting to internet solution on a mac]

---

***Edit: This is the fix for a situation when the emulator's wifi has changed the DNS to some non-working DNS.*** While this works most of the time, there might also be other reasons which may not fix from this solution.

Comment: run into this using android 8 Oreo emulators (AVDs) on android studio. either cli flag and system wide dns change fixed it.

Comment: N.B. It is mandatory to shut-down and then restart the emulator. If you restart emulator from android settings, it won't work

Comment: This, and a cold boot of the AVD fixed it

Comment: Actually, entering any valid *public* DNS server address should work, no need to use Google DNS specifically. By default it's often your router's address which is set as the DNS (or none, which on most system falls back to your router). Your router then will figure out the correct DNS as per its config. However this does not work for the emulator as the emulator can't directly connect to your router or use it as DNS I suppose. Therefore the need for a static public DNS IP.

Comment: the first time this didn't work. Just worked after enabled and disabled airplane mode. After doing that is like it reboots everything and it began working

Comment: Yeap! It's mandatory to shut down the emulator. Thanks for the solution

Comment: After switching off and starting up the emulator again, it worked for me.

Answer (score 209):

My solution using Mac OSX 10.13

I read about it being caused by LAN card and WiFi being enabled, and some approaches seemed complicated to me, so I simply tried this, and it worked:

- Disabled WiFi on my laptop.
- Switched off the emulator.
- Did a cold boot on the emulator (AVD Manager -> on emulator actions -> Cold Boot Now).
- After reboot with laptop WiFi disabled the emulator showed proper WiFi connection (emulator still shows AndroidWifi but is connected to my laptop internet. WiFi symbol now look like this: [WiFi symbol connected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/45oTb.png))
- I then enabled WiFi on my laptop and everything worked.

Comment: This worked and I did a "wipe data" before "cold boot" and had to configure WiFi in the emulator, there was a notification when swiping down on the home screen.

Comment: Worked for me! I just did a cold boot with wifi disabled and it worked just fine.

Comment: Amazing!!! Thanks!!! But for me - I had to disable and enable Wi-fi on emulator too.

Comment: This is a much better solution than modifying global DNS settings on your computer.

Comment: @StephanBakkelundValois in early 2021, it worked for me, too, except that I didn’t have to do a cold boot. I just turned off my laptop's connection, restarted the emulator, then connected to the AndroidWifi network, and the internet access worked again.

Comment: After countless hours scouring the internet for the workable solution and to no avail, a cold boot with WiFi OFF is all it takes.

Comment: I wiped the data first but it worked

Comment: Worked in mid 2023 AS Flamingo | 2022.2.1 Patch 1, thanks

Comment: I logged-in to my personal Stack Overflow account from my work computer just to upvote this answer and the comments of it. This killed more than an hour of my time out of nowhere.

Answer (score 203):

It doesn't matter if you are using **Windows** or **MAC**, **you do not have to change your local PC network settings!**

The older answers to this problem **no longer work after 2020** (Using Android Studio 4.1.2 or newer).  The problem is the DNS settings on the Emulator.  It no longer works to just change the DNS Servers on your local PC.  You have to change the DNS settings within the Emulator.  The following steps are for an emulator running Android 11.  Other versions will be similar:

1. Open the ***Extended controls*** dialog that opens up to the right of the emulator. Click on ***Settings*** on the dialog menu. Click on ***Proxy*** at the top and make sure *Use Android Studio Http proxy settings* IS CHECKED.  I emphasize this because many of the previous solutions said to uncheck this.  However, on the latest versions, it works better to keep this checked.  If it wasn't already checked, restart the emulator before proceeding Step 2. (NOTE: If your version doesn't show the Proxy Settings, then you can skip this step. We just want to make sure the Proxy settings are changed back to the default settings.)
2. Navigate to the WiFi connection settings within the emulator:  ***Home*** Screen -> Swipe up -> ***Settings*** -> ***Network & Internet*** -> ***Internet (AndroidWifi)*** -> click gear icon next to AndroidWiFi -> click ***Advanced*** dropdown near bottom of screen *(If this option is not available for you its okay just skip this step and move to next one i.e. Swipe up)* -> Swipe up to view to view ***Network Details***.
3. What does it say for ***DNS***.  If it is NOT 8.8.8.8, follow this to fix.  Write down (or remember) the ***IP address*** and ***Gateway*** address displayed there in the network settings. We need those IP addresses to fill in as static.
4. Click the pencil icon on the top to edit the ***Network details***.  Click the ***IP settings*** dropdown and change it to **Static**.  Then enter the ***IP address*** and ***Gateway*** that you wrote down in step 2.  Make sure ***DNS 1*** is 8.8.8.8 and ***DNS 2*** is 8.8.4.4.  These filled in automatically for me.
5. Close the emulator and restart it using the ***Cold Boot Now*** option.

This fixed it for me after I unsuccessfully tried all the other solutions found on this page and many others.  I hope it works for you.

Comment: Where is the Extended controls?

Comment: Never mind, I should uncheck "Run in a tool window"

Comment: I have tried all above solution but didn't work, this is the only solution that worked perfectly. cheers

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me except I needed to uncheck _Use Android Studio Proxy Settings_ and force _No proxy_ in step 1

Comment: Followed step by step and found that the DNS had changed for some reason. Got it to work after following your steps.

Comment: There is no IP settings options

Comment: This worked for me also, behind a VPN and Proxy in a corporate network.

Comment: Worked on Android Emulator 31.1.4 and Android Studio Arctic Fox | 2020.3.1 Patch 4

Comment: The proxy setting does not seem to appear when the emulator is embedded in Android Studio. But it appears to be okay to ignore this setting.

Comment: Thanks for pointed that out @jeiea.  It is true that you don't need to change the Proxy Setting - The reason we mentioned it was in the old version you had to change it and many of the other instructions referred to that old version.  Many of our readers had already followed the instruction that said to change the Proxy Setting.  That is why we said to make sure the Proxy setting is checked.  But if your version doesn't show the proxy setting, then that is better yet.  I updated the solution to include your comment.

Comment: i try this but it constantly connecting and disconnecting when using a static IP address

Comment: Working solution. Thanks. Also didn't require rebooting the emulator. Just disconnecting and reconnecting to AndroidWifi fixed it for me.

Comment: In step 5 you said write down ip address and gateway address but there is no mentioned of ip address and gateway address in step 2. I don't understand that.

Comment: For me worked directly after I turned off my open vpn, without any such changes, in DNS it still shows 10.0.2.3, device pixel 7 pro API 34.

Answer (score 29):

On macOS:

1. Open **Network** in **System Preferences**.
2. Select your current network from left side then click **Advanced...**.
3. Change **Configure IPv6**(under **TCP/IP** tab) from **Automatically** to **Link-local only**.
4. Restart your emulator.

Comment: If only this wouldn't kill IPv6 on the host mac :(

Comment: it works for latest mac os

Answer (score 22):

**Solution for Windows:**

1. Go to your Android SDK Location, E.g.: *C:\Users\shehzad\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator*.
2. Open Command Prompt on same location. Write this command: `emulator -avd Nexus_4_API_29 -gpu host -dns-server 8.8.8.8`. Here `Nexus_4_API_29` will be your emulator device name (You can find it out devices list from Android Studio -> AVD Manager). This command will run your specified device and WIFI will have Internet connected.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, this only worked for me. Earlier it was showing Connected, but no Internet. After implementing your solution this started working.

Comment: @ashishdhiman2007 Good to hear that your problem solved using my solution :)

Comment: the best and simplest answer, also the only one that worked for me.

Comment: @curiouscoder sound good :)

Comment: Ubuntu 22.04 - The only working solution - `/home/{USER}/Android/Sdk/emulator/emulator -avd {AVM_NAME} -gpu host -dns-server {DNS_IP};` thanks @Shehzad

Comment: lint! this still works well for MasOS Ventura 13.4 in 2023 

Answer (score 20):

My environment is  Android Studio 4.2.0 in  Mac 11.3.1 Big Sur

**Step 0.**
I close all of my emulator, and close Android Studio too .

**Step 1.**
Then I open Android Studio.
AVD Manager -> Cold Boot Now
[image]

**Step 2.**
Close Wifi on emulator.
Then LTE can work
[image]

**Step 3.** (Optional)
By the way, My DNS setting of my mac Network is
[image]

If step0 -> step 1 -> step 2 is not work, you can set DNS like step 3.  and then go through Step0 -> Step1 -> Step2 again.

And it will work.

Comment: cold boot worked for me!!!

Answer (score 14):

I was having the same issue and following the below steps resolved it.

Steps:

1. Go to Emulator Settings
2. Select Proxy Tab
3. Then check the "Use Android Studio HTTP proxy settings" option
4. Click Apply

[image]

Comment: This is not set by default. Thanks

Answer (score 14):

On Mac OSX (Catalina for me), the problem is caused by the fact that the emulator automatically picks up the nameserver by looking at /etc/resolv.conf and picking the first one, in my case an IPv6 address. Source: https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-networking#dns

Simply edit the file (sudo vi /etc/resolv.conf) and move the IPv4 address (192.168.1.1 in my case) to be first, before the IPv6 addresses. Seriously, that was it.

Comment: thanks, this one works for me. i'm using macOS catalina 10.15

Comment: I had to restart the emulator and it worked immediately... And only because I now have IPV6 :(

Answer (score 11):

I have solved with google dns on network adapter `8.8.8.8` and `8.8.4.4`

[image: Android Emulator wifi connected with no internet solution for windows]

Comment: Hopefully this is reported as bug somewhere because it also took some time for me.

Answer (score 10):

Wipe data by right clicking on virtual device list  & cold boot works for me..

Answer (score 9):

Well, I did it this way:

Steps to add manual proxy:

1. Go to **Emulator settings**
2. Go to **Proxy** tab
3. Set **Manual proxy configuration**
4. Add your **Host name** & **Port number**
5. Click on **Apply**

#### Reference screen shot:

[image]

Hope it helps.

Comment: How do you find your hostname?

Answer (score 9):

**100% Working on Windows 10**

**Android AVD come with Google DSN configured inside emulators.
So we need to set same to network sharing for accessing same.**

**Google Public DNS IP addresses
The Google Public DNS IP addresses (IPv4) are as follows:**

8.8.8.8

8.8.4.4

**The Google Public DNS IPv6 addresses are as follows:**

2001:4860:4860::8888
2001:4860:4860::8844
**You can use either address as your primary or secondary DNS server.**

[More Info](https://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns/docs/using)

Here I show for setting v4 IP steps

1. Open Network and Sharing Center
2. Right Click on current internet connection
3. Select Properties
4. Double Click on Internet Protocol Version 4 (TCP/IPv4)
5. Select Use the following DNS server address
6. Set the Preferred and Alternate DNS server
7. Prefered DNS Server : 8.8.8.8
8. Alternate DNS Server : 8.8.4.4
9. Click on OK
10. Restart Android AVD

**Note : If VPN is enabled then it will not work need to disconnect your VPN**

[image: More info on Google DSN]

Comment: Sadly we need VPN when WFH. Can't believe Google have left this issue for many years.

Answer (score 8):

**On Windows :**

After testing some solutions, I worked on my case by clicking the down arrow on the AVD, option "Cold Boot Now".
after booting, Android has access to the internet.

Answer (score 6):

Maybe this would help someone. I tried all the solutions above. Changing DNS, cold booting, etc. After several hours of trial and error, I went to the official docs, which said that the emulator picks up the DNS config. of host machine at emulator's boot time.
I had VMWare installed on my machine, which installs a few network adapters. So, **I just changed the DNS config. of all the adapters (including VMWare adapters), and cold booted my emulator.** OMG, the problem which didn't seem to go away for hours, just got right!

Now, what I find odd is, I switched back the DNS config. of all the adapters to auto, and cold booted my emulator again. The WiFi still works just fine. **OS: Windows 10.**

Comment: I just needed to cold boot the emulator

Answer (score 6):

If you have any VPN connected - try disconnecting it.

For me it was VPN through `Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client`. Once I've closed the Cisco client (which terminates the VPN connection), WiFi on Android emulator started working.

Comment: I also have this VPN. In my case I first disconnect the VPN, then restart an emulator ("Cold Boot Now"). Then the emulator connects to the Internet. After that connect to the VPN again, and the emulator continues to work.

Comment: Also it depends on the VPN URL. An emulator working over "Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client" may or may not connect to the Internet with different VPN URLs.

Comment: @CoolMind Does it work ? I am facing the same issue but the approach you mentioned does not work for me :-(

Comment: @RakeshL, I have 2 different URLS from two companies. First connects to their resources and other URLs, but an emulator doesn't connect. Second connects to their resources (Git) and other, but the emulator connects to any URL. Strange. If you try to start an emulator before connecting to VPN, will it work?

Comment: @CoolMind Before connecting to VPN, the Internet is connected. But without VPN , it is getting disconnected.

Comment: @RakeshL, today my VPN hasn't allowed a connection. In this case I launched an emulator with Google DNS, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/42784657/2914140.

Answer (score 6):

I hope I save someone a lot of pain, **I tried everything** everyone said on here, changed the DNS of every network adapter, reinstalled everything, the SDK, the emulator, even android studio, nothing worked, if you find yourself in the same position check if you VMware installed, if you do, don't bother with the DNS just go into **Control Panel->Network and Sharing Center->Change Adapter Settings, and disable any and all VMware Network Adapters, then Cold Boot, fixes the issue instantly**, you can even enable them later, and it still works

Answer (score 6):

There are 2 ways to fix this bug.

1. You should turn off android emulator and [cold boot] again.
   If the first method doesn't work ...
2. You should turn on [Plane Mode] (on top menu of screen) and after a sec turn off again.
   Then Wi-Fi will connect to the internet.

Answer (score 4):

A simple cold boot worked for me, no need to start other emulators or wiping memory.

Just close your emulator and select the "Cold Boot Now" option on the drop menu adjacent to the play button. If not look for any of the more comprehensive options listed here, but I suggest always starting with the simplest solution.

Good luck!

Answer (score 4):

I tried all of these solutions with no results. I am using **Windows 10 OS**

What *finally* worked for me was:

**1. Closing all instances of AVD devices**

**2. Navigating to:**

```
C:\Users\userName\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator
```

**3. Then entering the following command:**

```
.\emulator.exe -avd avd_device_name -dns-server 8.8.8.8
```

Answer (score 3):

What worked for me:

- Power off the emulator (using its power key)
- Start your app on ANOTHER emulator and then close it.
- Now start your app in previous emulator again.

Answer (score 3):

Solution for issue on **Apple M1**:

1. Install one of the newest canary versions of Android Studio. Use the MAC ARM version (Apple Silicon).
2. When creating a new virtual device use API Level S and arm64 virtual image. (could be found in other images)

Here is the link for the android studio releases list:
https://developer.android.com/studio/archive

(Worked for me)

Answer (score 3):

After doing these steps make sure you don't have any **VPN software active**.

```
Open Network and Sharing Center

Right Click on current internet connection

Select Properties

Double Click on Internet Protocol Version 4 (TCP/IPv4)

Select Use the following DNS server address

Set the Preferred and Alternate DNS server

Prefered DNS Server : 8.8.8.8

Alternate DNS Server : 8.8.4.4

Click on OK

Restart Android AVD
```

Answer (score 2):

If the wifi spot has changed, simple restart the emulator so the emulator refresh network settings from dhcp service.

Answer (score 2):

Resetting Network Settings on Android Emulator fixes this issue.

Answer (score 2):

For new searcher users:
**Sometimes VPN is your solution**
Changing of network setting is not possible always because of networking issues.
If you are in ip addresses that google does not responding for these regions,your solution is using of vpn.Use a proper vpn (a vpn that trough it you could update your android studio).When your vpn is on start your avd device (ofcourse api level of your emulator is important for example I have not any problem with api 22 but for api 28 is need using of vpn !).This was my experience about android emulator internet.

Answer (score 2):

Change the location of the emulator and set it to your current location.

- Steps : -

  1. Click on More in emulator options
  2. Go to location
  3. Search your address and click SET LOCATION

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue - in the emulator I was connected to the wifi/lte but I couldn't access any website.

The solution for me was to fix the IP of my home DNS server:

```
$ cat /etc/resolv.conf 
search home
nameserver 192.168.1.1 #was 192.168.0.1 - it used to work when I was connected to a different router
nameserver 1.1.1.1
nameserver 1.0.0.1
```

you don't really need to use google dns

Answer (score 2):

**If anyone quick fix:**

Step 1: Go to AVD Manager

Step 2: Stop the device

Step 3: Run Android Studio project

Answer (score 2):

Under Extended Controls ( which can be enabled by pressing the more button (3 dots ... ) at bottom.

Then under Proxy tab, Select no proxy.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try using LAN if available. That works as a charm for me...

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem that was kind of weird. The emulator used to work just fine but then I went to a cafe and connected to their wifi then the emulator wifi stopped working. I wiped the data made cold boot from the AVD manager then everything worked without any change in settings. I guess cold boot only would have worked without wiping data so you might try that before wiping the data.

Answer (score 1):

On Android Studio 4.2, I was experience this issue where both Emulator Wifi/LTE was connected but no internet.

Solutions that did NOT work for me: Turning Wifi on and off, setting location/proxy, cold booting, wiping data, VPN, etc. None of the other solutions were working.

Solution that worked for me: Upgrading to Android Studio 4.2.1 and rebooting emulator.

Answer (score 1):

None of this worked for me then I turned on "Mobile HotSpot" on windows. It exists on Taskbar next to "Airplane Mode". Everything started working.

Answer (score 1):

I tried all the above in WINDOWS 11 system without results.
Finally i ran the check disk - chkdsk c: /f /r - and after PC restart i recreated the device. And it's finally worked.

Answer (score 1):

My situation is I have internet connection in browser but not in Google map/Google play store. So I try to disable my VPN. Then it solve this issue and my emulator network is active

Answer (score 1):

My case, emulator android 11.
If you use WARP 1.1.1.1 on Mac, try turn it on, it would help.

Answer (score 0):

This may not solve everyone's problem but I disconnected my wifi and used the Ethernet connection. This resolved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try disabling your antivirus and then restart your emulator that helped in my case.

Comment: Probably not safe approach to disable antivirus, why to have it on the first place? Maybe in your case antivirus was blocking some ports.

Answer (score 0):

Just restarting the android studio resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me in mac was going to

```
File > Restart IDE
```