# Google maps is not installed or disabled

Tags: flutter, dart

I have an app that user google navigation but as I am trying to use it it says:
"google maps is not installed or disabled". I have read in the internet that this is an Android 11 issue. Any thoughts how to fix this?

Comment: Try this solution. - https://stackoverflow.com/a/55505466/6255492

Answer (score 16, accepted):

To fix this, you will need to add the Google Maps package "com.google.android.apps.maps" as an entry in your AndroidManifest.xml  entry:

```
<manifest package="com.your.package">
  <queries>
    <package android:name="com.google.android.apps.maps" />
  </queries>
  ...
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution that worked perfectly was:

Install the **Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Maps** package from NuGet Packages to Xamarin.Android project. That's it!

That's all and the problem was gone. Working perfectly now.

You can try installing the latest version but if you can't because other plugins also need to be updated. Then you can just select a lower version and install it until you get the one that works.