# Having a problem with Google Maps Flutter on real Android device

Tags: java, android, flutter, google-maps

I created stateful widget that is used throughout the app to display a map with markers. I need to show a map on a screen in order to give users a better experience. I'm only writing this because SO says that I have too much code in this question.

The map displays fine on the iOS emulator. Haven't checked on a real iOS device yet.

I'm using `google_maps_flutter: ^2.2.1`

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter.dart';

class GoogleMapWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  final double lat;
  final double lng;
  final String name;
  final String id;
  const GoogleMapWidget({
    Key? key,
    required this.lat,
    required this.lng,
    required this.name,
    required this.id,
  }) : super(key: key);
  @override
  State<GoogleMapWidget> createState() => _GoogleMapWidgetState();
}

class _GoogleMapWidgetState extends State<GoogleMapWidget> {
  final Completer<GoogleMapController> mapController = Completer();
  List<Marker> markers = <Marker>[];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    markers.add(
      Marker(
        markerId: MarkerId(widget.id),
        position: LatLng(widget.lat, widget.lng),
        infoWindow: InfoWindow(title: widget.name),
      ),
    );
    return SizedBox(
      width: 350.0,
      height: 400.0,
      child: GoogleMap(
        initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
          target: LatLng(widget.lat, widget.lng),
          zoom: 15.0,
        ),
        mapType: MapType.normal,
        markers: Set<Marker>.of(markers),
        onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller) {
          mapController.complete(controller);
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The widget is used like this:

```
   GoogleMapWidget(
     name: name,
     id: 'single_screen',
     lat: lat,
     lng: lng,
   ),
```

I connected a Samsung S10 to the computer and did `flutter run`

When entering the screen that uses the map widget I get this:

```
D/OpenGLRenderer( 4700): eglCreateWindowSurface
E/FrameEvents( 4700): updateAcquireFence: Did not find frame.
```

And when exiting:

```
V/GoogleMapController( 4700): Controller was disposed before GoogleMap was ready.
E/PlatformViewsController( 4700): Disposing platform view threw an exception
E/PlatformViewsController( 4700): java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.util.LinkedList.isEmpty()' on a null object reference
E/PlatformViewsController( 4700):       at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.DeferredLifecycleHelper.zae(com.google.android.gms:play-services-base@@18.0.1:1)
E/PlatformViewsController( 4700):       at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.DeferredLifecycleHelper.onDestroy(com.google.android.gms:play-services-base@@18.0.1:2)
E/PlatformViewsController( 4700):       at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView.onDestroy(com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps@@18.0.0:1)
E/PlatformViewsController( 4700):       at io.flutter.plugins.googlemaps.GoogleMapController.destroyMapViewIfNecessary(GoogleMapController.java:891)
E/PlatformViewsController( 4700):       at io.flutter.plugins.googlemaps.GoogleMapController.dispose(GoogleMapController.java:578)
E/PlatformViewsController( 4700):       at io.flutter.plugin.platform.PlatformViewsController$1.dispose(PlatformViewsController.java:376)
E/PlatformViewsController( 4700):       at io.flutter.embedding.engine.systemchannels.PlatformViewsChannel$1.dispose(PlatformViewsChannel.java:135)
E/PlatformViewsController( 4700):       at io.flutter.embedding.engine.systemchannels.PlatformViewsChannel$1.onMethodCall(PlatformViewsChannel.java:63)
E/PlatformViewsController( 4700):       at io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel$IncomingMethodCallHandler.onMessage(MethodChannel.java:262)
E/PlatformViewsController( 4700):       at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.invokeHandler(DartMessenger.java:295)
E/PlatformViewsController( 4700):       at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.lambda$dispatchMessageToQueue$0$io-flutter-embedding-engine-dart-DartMessenger(DartMessenger.java:319)
E/PlatformViewsController( 4700):       at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.run(Unknown Source:12)
E/PlatformViewsController( 4700):       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
E/PlatformViewsController( 4700):       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E/PlatformViewsController( 4700):       at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:226)
E/PlatformViewsController( 4700):       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:313)
E/PlatformViewsController( 4700):       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8663)
E/PlatformViewsController( 4700):       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/PlatformViewsController( 4700):       at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:567)
E/PlatformViewsController( 4700):       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1135)
D/OpenGLRenderer( 4700): setSurface called with nullptr
D/OpenGLRenderer( 4700): setSurface() destroyed EGLSurface
D/OpenGLRenderer( 4700): destroyEglSurface
```

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.3.4, on macOS 12.6 21G115 darwin-x64, locale en-EN)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 13.4.1)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[!] Android Studio (not installed)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.72.0)
[✓] Connected device (4 available)
[✓] HTTP Host Availability
```

Comment: Is your manifest registering the API key and allowing the correct permissions to use this package? Potential answer if that's already there: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57864082/9063088

Comment: Yeah ... I added the `<meta-data` element in `AndroidManifest.xml` and used the api key from the console. I feel like that's where the problem is. Gotta try out a few more things in the console settings. The Android key (auto created by Firebase) has no restrictions set.