# What does 'ApiExpception: 7' mean when using Google sign-in through Firebase?

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication, google-signin

When trying to use Google sign-in through Firebase Authentication in Flutter, I am getting an error:

```
flutter com.google.android.gms.common.api.apiexception: 7
```

I did not find any solution for this problem anywhere. What does this mean?

Answer (score 37):

This error occurs when you are not connect to the internet.
Check your connection and try again.

Comment: nop, my emulator has accessed to the internet

Comment: Same problem, the phone can access the network, and the phone time is right, I am pretty sure.

Comment: I didn't realize my Android emulator had somehow lost WiFi connection, so this answer along with this solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/57305704/1411056 resolved the problem for me.

Comment: I got the error when my device was connected to WLAN but has no connection to the internet. For example when you're at a hotel with free wifi but you have first to accepted their rules.

Answer (score 10):

*Terrible* error messaging here by Google, so good question!

From the Java docs for [`ApiException`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/api/ApiException), it says that the exception has a method `getStatusCode`, which returns:

> Status code resulting from the operation. The value is one of the constants in [`CommonStatusCodes`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/api/CommonStatusCodes) or specific to the API in use.

They mention that `getMessage()` will return "a summary of the cause" so assuming that they're just echoing back the status code and using that as a summary, 7 maps to [`NETWORK_ERROR`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/api/CommonStatusCodes#NETWORK_ERROR) from `CommonStatusCodes`:

> `public static final int NETWORK_ERROR`
>
> A network error occurred. Retrying should resolve the problem.
>
> Constant Value: 7

Answer (score 0):

In my case my phone date and time was wrong once i make it correct Google sign in working perfectly.