# Can't connect to the development server iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

I wasted a day and a half and still can't figure out what is going on and can't find any working solutions. I can't debug my react native application on a real device. It worked yesterday in the morning. Now it is not working. As for me, I didn't change anything. XCode always loads a pre-bundled file. I am on the same working wifi. There are no issues with emulators, only real device.

When I am creating a personal hotspot on my iPhone and connect through it - it works! But I don't want to use a personal hotspot, I want to use wifi.

What I tried:

```
 1. Reload laptop
 2. Reload Mobile
 3. Change the IP address to the local inside of AppDelegate.m
 4. Clean build
 5. Remove and install node_modules
 6. Kill -9 everything that runs on port 8081
 7. Enable App Transport Security (Xcode)
 8. Connect-disconnect the device
```

Comment: Sometimes stopping and starting Xcode seems to fix it for me.

Answer (score 0):

Go to **Settings**>**Network**>**Advanced....**>**DNS**
Add these two entries

```
8.8.8.8
8.8.4.4
```

If the entries field is disabled and you're not able to edit it, click on the 'Lock' icon in the bottom area of that window and enter the password to be able to make changes
Possible Duplicate:
[Android Studio - Android Emulator Wifi Connected with No Internet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50670547/android-studio-android-emulator-wifi-connected-with-no-internet)

Comment: These entries are present and the same on desktop and mobile