# Azure sql connection hangs using JTDS

Tags: java, jdbc, azure-sql-database, jtds

I am trying to connect to an Azure SQL server using the JTDS JDBC driver. I have gotten the connection to work previously, but overnight it now hangs on

`DriverManager.getConnection(url);`

It gives me no exception, and continues running past the 30 second timeout that is default in the connection string. Full code is below

```
        try {
            StrictMode.ThreadPolicy pol = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(pol);

            Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver");
            String url = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://{server}.database.windows.net:1433;database=PROD;user={username}@{server};password={password};encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=false;hostNameInCertificate=*.database.windows.net;loginTimeout=30;";
            Connection c = DriverManager.getConnection(url);

            c.close();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            new AlertDialog.Builder().setTitle("e").setMessage(e.getMessage()).setNegativeButton("e", null).show();
        }
```

I am able to connect to and query the database using SSMS, so as far as I can tell the database is working correctly. Though I am a very beginner on using SQL servers so I may be wrong. I found that the SQL server version is `12.0.2000.8`. JTDS documentation suggests changing the TDS version in some cases, but from what I tried that didnt solve my issues. I am using JTDS version 1.3.1.

Again, this method was working fine yesterday and now I am having issues. Nothing in the project was changed. Yesterday I wasn't closing the connection after creating it, so I have a hunch that there is some issue with that on the SQL Server.

Now, a couple hours later, the connection went through after a few seconds, and when I tried to rerun the app it had the same issue.

**Found my solution:**

Seems that the android emulator had an issue with DNS. Following [Android Studio - Android Emulator Wifi Connected with No Internet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50670547/android-studio-android-emulator-wifi-connected-with-no-internet) this thread I was able to manually set my DNS to `8.8.8.8` and `8.8.4.4` which resolved the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Congratulation that you have found the solutions:

Seems that the android emulator had an issue with DNS. Following [Android Studio - Android Emulator Wifi Connected with No Internet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50670547/android-studio-android-emulator-wifi-connected-with-no-internet) this thread I was able to manually set my DNS to `8.8.8.8` and `8.8.4.4` which resolved the issue.

I post this as answer and this can be beneficial to other community members.