# com.microsoft.identity.client.exception.MsalClientException: Unable to perform cloud discovery

Tags: android, azure-ad-b2c

I am getting this error:

```
com.microsoft.identity.client.exception.MsalClientException: Unable to perform cloud discovery
```

when calling this method:

```
b2cApp.acquireToken(parameters);
```

from this object:

```
private IMultipleAccountPublicClientApplication b2cApp;
```

I have looked through a few threads:

[Unable to perform cloud discovery #443](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-android/issues/443)

[Unable to perform cloud discovery error from MSAL library of Android #676](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-android/issues/676)

[Unable to perform cloud discovery error from MSAL library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56889405/unable-to-perform-cloud-discovery-error-from-msal-library)

I can't tell if this is an Android configuration issues (allowing the discovery) or if there is some issue with my Msal configuration. I think the former as I would hope to get a better error message back specifically referencing what could not be discovered. I believe there is a reference to that in the GitHub link as well. Any thoughts?

Comment: Hi @Icj, Please help us with the steps to reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added these two lines to the AndroidMainfest.xml file based on information provided by the Azure B2C team:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Answer (score 0):

This occurs when **emulator loses access to the internet/network**.  Opening the Chrome browser indicates no websites (such as google.com) can be loaded.

As suggested by [other questions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50670547) & answers, I tinkered with my **DNS network settings** (such as turning on DHCP assigned DNS; not sure how that got turned off) and disconnected/reconnected my Ethernet cable.