# firestore returning null react native android

Tags: javascript, android, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

Im trying to display the contents of my firestore database, its working perfectly on ios but android is null, i've followed the instructions on https://rnfirebase.io/ for the android set up to the T and i've created multiple new apps to no avail.

[image]

Firebase is acknowledging that there are 2 apps connected but no matter what I do, nothing is being shown.

[image]

Ive updated the rules to accept any connections but still nothing. 
***Has anyone else run into this problem?*** Any information needed can be provided, but seeing as the app is working fine on ios i'm going crazy trying to figure out whats wrong

```
export default function Products(){
const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
    const subscriber = firestore()
    .collection('products')
    .onSnapshot(querySnapshot => {
        const products = [];

        querySnapshot.forEach(documentSnapshot => {
            products.push({
                ...documentSnapshot.data(),
                key: documentSnapshot.id,
            });
        });
        setProducts(products);
        setLoading(false);
    });

    return () => subscriber();
}, []);


return(
    <View>
        <Text>Top</Text>
         <FlatList
        data={products}
        renderItem={({ item }) => (
        <View style={{height: 50, flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center'}}>
            <Text>Product ID: {item.key}</Text>
            <Text>Product Name: {item.name}</Text>
        </View>

    )}
    />
    <Text>Bottom</Text>
    </View>
);
```

}

Comment: Have you added the google-services.json to the Android folder?

Comment: I've added it to the android/app folder

Comment: Your android emulator screenshot shows a connection error on the wifi icon. Can you open any webpage from the emulator browser? It comes with Google Chrome installed, could you check that?

Comment: I've had a look and youre right! it says connected with no internet, I've tried to fix it via this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50670547/android-studio-android-emulator-wifi-connected-with-no-internet but it doesnt work, do you have any ideas / resources on how i can fix it?

Comment: Nevermind it works!! I had to delete and reinstall the emulator after i made the changes. Thanks man! I owe you a degree!!

Comment: Can you post an answer here in case somebody else has the same issue?

Comment: Sure, done. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Damn, the internet on the android emulator wasn't working (can see in the picture the little x by the wifi cone), followed this post [Android Studio - Android Emulator Wifi Connected with No Internet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50670547/android-studio-android-emulator-wifi-connected-with-no-internet)

Make sure to delete and reinstall the emulator and you'll be good to go