# Trouble connecting Android emulator to the internal network via VPN

Tags: android, emulation

I'm having an issue with connecting my Android emulator to the internal network via VPN.
I tried everything included in this StackOverflow page,
[Android Studio - Android Emulator Wifi Connected with No Internet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50670547/android-studio-android-emulator-wifi-connected-with-no-internet)

Can somebody help me with this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: i had to turned off the WLAN/wi-fi on my emulator and then it works. Hope it helps

Comment: @WhatAJerk, do you mean that you have turned Wi-Fi on an emulator and retained Mobile data / LTE? It also doesn't work in my case.

Comment: @CoolMind, i had to turn off the wifi

Comment: @WhatAJerk, thanks. I had to either: 1) disconnect VPN, start emulator and connect VPN, or 2) change VPN URL.

Answer (score -2):

I installed OpenVPN on Android Emulator and it worked.

Comment: Downvote because, saying it works for you even though there's a countless amount of issues that can potentially occur is really not helpful.

Comment: This method is extremely inconvenient, but for me it was the only solution to make the app works through VPN on macOS