# Android Studio 2021.3.1.17: Internet pages wont load

Tags: android-studio

I have installed Android Studio 2021.3.1.17 and when I click on Google Chrome in an Android device, the page will not load

The device is a Pixel 6 Pro API 33.
I have tried adding the advancedFeatures.ini text document as described in other posts and it doesn't work for me

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I have tried this and it does not work: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50670547/android-studio-android-emulator-wifi-connected-with-no-internet

I have deleted Android Studio twice and reinstalled it.

What code do you need to see and where can I easiestly find it to share with you?