# Android Emulator Wifi Connected with No Internet

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

I know this question has appeared multiple times on SO, but NONE of the answers helped, here's a list of what I've tried before:

- restarting the IDE
- invalidating the caches / rebuilding project
- wiping data & cold booting the emulator
- changing the gate and IP adress of the emulator (inside the wifi settings)
- .\emulator.exe -avd avd_device_name -dns-server 8.8.8.8 (the command with the correct avd_device_name, run inside the emulator folder)
- airplane mode
- Restarting my pc and my modem
- Creating a different emulator
- removing all files from .android dir
- restarting the adb-server
- cold-booting 8 times in a row
- Changing the DNS of the host machine
- Restarting the emulator "a couple of times"
- toggling the wi-fi button
- literally reinstalling android studio (currently running the newest version, it changed nothing)
- downgrading android studio
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/44214842/15749574 <- don't know how to even describe that one, but I tried it
- checking the "Use Android Studio HTTP proxy settings" option

I am not using a VPN, the emulator was working fine yesterday (things went wrong after shutting down the pc and starting it up again I guess?), I am not using a LAN connection

I'm starting the question again to seek help cause I've spent the last 15 hours on this and IT'S STILL NOT WORKING :(

I would normally just reinstall all of the OS (currently: Windows 11) (I'm not patient at all XD), but that's the company machine and I doubt that I have the "necessary powers" if you know what I mean

Update:
I've got an OS reinstall, the emulator worked fine on the company's wifi, but when I went back home it happened again, so it might be a network problem? (I've got a personal pc on the same network and the emulator on that pc works like a charm, I'm so confused)

Comment: I checked logs of the emulators and noticed 2 errors: 1) ServiceNotFoundException: No service published for: Ethernet 2) CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification not found, it might be related, I have no idea

Comment: noticed another one: 3) Failed to open QEMU pipe 'qemud:network': Invalid argument

Comment: Try to access with a different account.. I konw you would only have a single one. But ask someone else probably the IT guy to access. And test it out. Probably something went wrong on your account

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally managed to solve the issue! (but this post is still open to other solutions, cause definitevely I got lucky and there could be many other issues that would lead to the same problems)

After getting a fresh install of my OS and trying it out on the company network it was working as it is supposed to do, but when I took the pc home and started it up... the same stuff happened, now I was sure that it was not a hardware problem, nor a "windows related" (drivers etc.) problem, so the only thing left was the firewall (and/or other software that may interrupt the internet flow), I went into the wifi settings and marked my wi-fi as "private" (not public), cold booted the emulator and it finally worked!

(side note: Solving this took me about 4 days...)

Answer (score 1):

There could be multiple causes, but a common cause of connectivity issues for emulators on both macOS and Windows is DNS settings against the IP address of the network connection on the host computer.

I have also known this to impact outbound connections from local Kubernetes clusters on Windows computers. A while back, it took me days of head scratching to resolve the Kubernetes problem.

I recently had a related emulator issue on macOS, where only the simulated 3G T-Mobile connection worked, and not the simulated Wifi. I looked at my host computer's network connection on macOS and it included only `8.8.8.8`. I then added `8.8.4.4`, as suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50670547/android-studio-android-emulator-wifi-connected-with-no-internet), and it resolved the problem.

[image][image]

Comment: I solved my issue, but I do not want the bounty to go to waste, so here ya go king

Answer (score 0):

It is my solution when I encounter this problem:
I shut down the emulator using the long click on the power button and select the power off on the screen like so:

[image]

Then I press the x button (close the emulator) immediately during the shutdown process.

[image]

Make sure you do not have any active VPN and start your emulator again using Android Studio.

Comment: Unfortunately, it did not work