# Android emulator error " Connected to device. Can't provide internet " How to solve?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

error
wifi not connecting

[image]

[image]

I have already tried these solutions.
**[Android Studio - Android Emulator Wifi Connected with No Internet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50670547/android-studio-android-emulator-wifi-connected-with-no-internet)**

And every where I saw this solution. I tried that also

[image]

but not worked but in the this question **[Android Studio - Android Emulator Wifi Connected with No Internet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50670547/android-studio-android-emulator-wifi-connected-with-no-internet)** I tried
[image]
this solution that's worked for me. Unfortunately when i shutdown and reOn my laptop I  have to run that command. And also when i delete android API from android studio and when redownload the android and re create emulator then wifi is connecting for that time but when restart the windows then again i have to face the same issue. I couldn't understand what's the error for that.
and also i have changed the emulator wifi dns like this
[image]

but not it's not worked for me.

**my emulator android version is android 13
android studio is " Flamingo 2022.2.1 "**

How I solve this ?

Comment: You are using windows?

Comment: @Dinesh yeah. windows 11

Comment: Then try my below solution it worked perfectly for me

Comment: Thank you for your support! I have already tried it but it didn't work

Answer (score 1):

For Windows users, you need to change the setting in your system/laptop.

1. Go to **network and internet option**->

[image]

2. Open **Ethernet or wifi**(for which you are connected) option ->
   [image]
3. Click on **change adapter option** ->
   [image]
4. Right-click on the network for which you have connected.
   [image]
5. A dialog box will be opened and just click on the Internet protocol version (TCP/IPv4) option.

[image]

Another dialog box will be opened and there just neglect the first set about the IP address (Keep as it is set) and click radio button of Use the following DNS server addresses: and enter as 8.8.8.8 in Preferred DNS server: and 8.8.4.4 in Alternate DNS server:

[image]

Now restart the emulator.

Comment: Thank you for your support! I have already tried it but it didn't work

Comment: Make sure you turn off T-Mobile data and restart emulator

Comment: now , i tried that also but not worked