# Android Studio Emulator : Wi-Fi connectd, no Internet

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-studio, android-emulator

I'm programming an online application and the problem is **Emulator** can't connect to Internet. Wi-Fi is connected but it says no Internet.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vkm6X.png)

**The steps I have taken so far, but the problem has not been solved:**

1- Change system DNS settings to **8.8.8.8** .

2- Deleting and reinstalling the emulator .

3- Installing different versions of the emulator with different APIs .

4 - going to settings in emulator and opening cellular and setting **meter** status to **Temporarily not metered** .

**Notice** : I'm using fodev proxy and I don't want it to change.

Comment: These answers may help you: https://stackoverflow.com/q/50670547/

Answer (score 0):

**On Windows Pc**

> Go to your Android SDK Location, `1.C:\Users\yourPcName\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator.`

2.Open Command Prompt on same location. Write this command:

```
emulator -avd Nexus_4_API_29 -gpu host -dns-server 8.8.8.8.
```

Here Nexus_4_API_29 will be your emulator device name (You can find it out devices list from Android Studio -> AVD Manager). This command will run your specified device and WIFI will have Internet connected.